# Display only rows with the max count value

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

I'm trying to extract only the rows with the maximum count from the following query:

```
SELECT FOO, BAR, COUNT(X)
FROM TABLE1, TABLE2, TABLE3
WHERE <CONDITIONS INVOLVING THE 3 TABLES>
GROUP BY FOO, BAR;
```

Which generates output that looks like -

```
FOO |  BAR        | COUNT(X)
 0     String 1       5
 1     String 2       3
 2     String 3       5
 3     String 4       4
 4     String 5       5
```

As you can see, there are 3 rows with a COUNT(X) value of 5. How would I edit this to ONLY display the rows that contain MAX(COUNT(X))? I am using Oracle SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with analytic functions. First find the count as for each set of values, as you are already; then use a `DENSE_RANK()` (or `RANK()`, or `ROW_NUMBER()`) function to assign an order to each rows in your existing result set base on the `COUNT()` value; and finally only pick the ones with the highest rank:

```
SELECT foo, bar, cnt
FROM (
    SELECT foo, bar, cnt,
        DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY cnt DESC) dr
    FROM(
        SELECT foo, bar, COUNT(x) cnt
        FROM ...
        GROUP BY foo, bar
    )
)
WHERE dr = 1;
```

Note the `DESC` in the the `ORDER BY`, so the highest `COUNT()` is assigned the rank of 1.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT FOO, BAR, MAX(X) maxX, COUNT(X) cntX
FROM TABLE1, TABLE2, TABLE3
WHERE <CONDITIONS INVOLVING THE 3 TABLES>
GROUP BY FOO, BAR
) A
WHERE maxX = cntX;
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I get an error that states: "group function is nested too deeply"

Comment: @Parkyprg - I don't think the OP wants reults where `max(x) = count(x)`, which gets ORA-01722 if `x` is not numeric; but those where `count(x) = (max(count(x))` over the whole result set. That either needs another query to find the max value, or analytics to do it one pass.

Comment: @Parkyprg thanks for the help but Alex is right! I'm after the rows where count is equal to the max(count(x)). So the correct output would just display 3 rows where count(X) == 5